# How can I use Firebase, Expo SDK 49, and Google Signin without using react-native-google-signin/google-signin?

Tags: node.js, firebase, expo, google-oauth

It appears implementing Google Authentication in a mobile app via Expo Go has changed, and the docs seem to say that `@react-native-google-signin/google-signin` is required, yet I cannot use `@react-native-google-signin/google-signin` as it requires Expo SDK 50, and some of my dependencies are incompatible with SDK 50 (I am on SDK 49).

I have tried using what I guess is the old method of Google Auth, but it doesn't work and results in an `Error 400: invalid_request`. I was hoping to be able to use `GoogleAuthProvider` from `firebase/auth` like this:

```
 const [request, response, promptAsync] = Google.useAuthRequest(
        {
            clientId: '',
            iosClientId: '',
            androidClientId: '',
            expoClientId: ''
        },
        Google
    );

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(response?.type)
        if (response?.type == "success") {
            const { id_token } = response.params;
            const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(id_token);
            signInWithCredential(null, credential)
        }
    }, [response]);
```

It seems to me that I need to specify my plist and json files for the `googleServicesFile` in my app.json, but this doesn't make sense to me, as they require using different apps, and my Firebase auth is on a web app. All of the tutorials and such online are either outdated or use `@react-native-google-signin/google-signin`. I'm welcome to any suggestions, I just want to be able to use `signInWithCredential` and not the way `@react-native-google-signin/google-signin` handles it.

Answer (score 0):

On mobile devices, doing most "social logins" requires use of native APIs.  Since Expo Go doesn't have those native APIs (or the NPM modules that leverage them) built into it, you then need to build a custom client.

...which you are going to have to do at some point anyways if you plan on distributing your app.  I wrote [an article about that here](https://www.buymeacoffee.com/gregfenton/expo-go-great-tool-release-custom-client).

Since you are using Firebase, I would recommend that you consider using [`@react-native-firebase`](https://rnfirebase.io/#expo) and its login providers that are supported by Firebase Authentication.